# iOS project:Why the long press gesture is so easy to be triggered?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Just as title says, when I update Xcode8, in my project, long press gesture is so easy to be triggered, even when I tap the screen, it call up! And the keyboard also have this problem. When I type a word, Xcode print the infomation like follow:

```
[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on <UIRemoteKeyboardWindow: 0x100ffb940; frame = (0 0; 414 736); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x17042d700>> without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring.
```

And in a view, I add a tap gesture and longpress gesture, when I tap(just touch), the gesture triggered is longpress, not tap gesture. This problem I have'not searched anywhere, so I come here to ask your help. (Forgive me, It is terrible on my English)

I post two pictures for you can know clearly.

[image: keyboard]

[image: textview]

This is my code:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer * lp = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(lp:)];
lp.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;
[_imageView addGestureRecognizer:lp];
- (void)lp:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)lp {
    if (lp.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(longPressImage)]) {
            [self.delegate longPressImage];
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally,This problem happend on some devices,not all devices.One device always happend,others just happend sometime,when I build project again ,it just OKO__O "…

Comment: Please post code.

Comment: Sorry, but it's hard to make sense of the question.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code showing how you create and setup the long press gesture and how you handle its events.

Comment: @shallowThought
`UILongPressGestureRecognizer * lp = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(lp:)];

        lp.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;

        [_imageView addGestureRecognizer:lp];


- (void)lp:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)lp {
    if (lp.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(longPressImage)]) {
            [self.delegate longPressImage];
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: @rmaddy
`UILongPressGestureRecognizer * lp = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(lp:)];

        lp.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;

        [_imageView addGestureRecognizer:lp];


- (void)lp:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)lp {
    if (lp.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(longPressImage)]) {
            [self.delegate longPressImage];
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: Sorry,but thanks for your goodness.@Eiko

Comment: As I said, update your question with relevant code. Don't post it in comments.

Comment: @rmaddy
Thanks,I updated my question.

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this?I have no any idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` instead of `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`. `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` triggered when touches are recognized as a start of some gesture. This gesture isn't necessary the long press you're looking for. Only at the point when recognizer state changes to `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` long press is performed as you expecting.

```
- (void)lp:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)lp {
    if (lp.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(longPressImage)]) {
            [self.delegate longPressImage];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I think this is not the solution,I try this,and it doesn't work.In my view,gesture wasn't the reason,may be the reason is  I use some runtime somewhere.Anyway,thanks!